# Delphi: how Add text to an image and save the new image?

Tags: image, delphi

the idea is retrieve date from a database (text and a picture) then add these data in another picture (like an ID form) then save the new picture.

how can this be done in delphi?

thx

Comment: Load the image into a TBitmap. Call TBitmap.Canvas.TextOut. Save the bitmap.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to rephrase your question; it sounds to me like a complete homework assignment, have you tried something ? To your questions: 1) *load image from DB* - there's a bunch of examples on the internet, just try to search one 2) *add these data in another picture* - what data do you want to add to what another picture and how ? Did you mean to load the picture from a DB along with some text, let's say with the image description, and draw this description on the image and save it somewhere ? And what is the ID form ?

Comment: @TLama yes, i loaded the image from the DB, and yea something like that. here s the ID form : http://i891.photobucket.com/albums/ac114/evilkidaz/ID.png i have to load the name,last name and the image from the DB and put them in their places in the form, then save it. i only have trouble in inserting these data in the picture

DavidHeffernan Thank you for your reply, but the text comes with a gray background. and can i change the font? make it bigger or change     the colors?

Edit: i found out how to insert the image by : [code]Image1.Canvas.Draw(1,1,graphic);[/code]

Comment: EDIT: Image1.Canvas.Font.Color := clRed;
  Image1.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;

found out the answer :) thx all

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the following:

```
uses
  PNGImage;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  PNGImage: TPNGImage;
  BlobStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  // create the PNG image instance
  PNGImage := TPNGImage.Create;
  try
    // assuming you have in the BlobStream variable the image from a DB loaded
    PNGImage.LoadFromStream(BlobStream);
    // setup the text background to be transparent
    PNGImage.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
    // optionally configure the font
    PNGImage.Canvas.Font.Size := 11;
    PNGImage.Canvas.Font.Color := clRed;
    PNGImage.Canvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];
    // and render it to the image's canvas
    PNGImage.Canvas.TextOut(5, 5, 'SomeText');
    // save this modified image to the file
    PNGImage.SaveToFile('c:\picture.png');
  finally
    // and finally free the PNG image instance
    PNGImage.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Here is an example how would I create my visit card (don't forget to save the [`necessary image`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/II7bT.png) file as `d:\llamas.png`):

```
uses
  GraphUtil, PNGImage;

procedure CreateCard(const AFileFile: string; AImage: TPNGImage;
  const AName, ASurname: string);
begin
  with TPNGImage.CreateBlank(COLOR_RGB, 8, 330, 160) do
  try
    GradientFillCanvas(Canvas, clWhite, $000080FF,
      Canvas.ClipRect, gdVertical);
    Canvas.StretchDraw(Rect(18, 18, 108, 108), AImage);
    Canvas.Pen.Width := 2;
    Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
    Canvas.Rectangle(5, 5, Width - 4, Height - 4);
    Canvas.Font.Size := 12;
    Canvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];
    Canvas.TextOut(110, 30, 'Form:  ' + AName + '  :.');
    Canvas.TextOut(125, 60, 'Genus:  ' + ASurname + '  :.');
    SaveToFile(AFileFile);
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  PNGImage: TPNGImage;
begin
  PNGImage := TPNGImage.Create;
  try
    // here you will load the image blob (by using LoadFromStream)
    // instead of LoadFromFile
    PNGImage.LoadFromFile('d:\llamas.png');
    CreateCard('d:\visit-card.png', PNGImage, 'Alpaca', 'Lama');
  finally
    PNGImage.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: @TLama The idiomatic Delphi way to deal with the background is to set `Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear`. Your way works but I don't see the need to use raw GDI here when the VCL wraps it up nicely.

Comment: @David, absolutely! I don't even know where did I assumed this. It must be from some old example I've seen a long time ago. Now I'm using my (GDI based) framework where the things like this are wrapped, so I didn't even think about it. Thanks for the hint!